# What is the solution of the following optimization problem?

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, convex-optimization

```
max g(x,y)= x*k+(1-x)*log(1+((x*y)*l)/(1-x))
s.t: 0<=x<=1,0<=y<=1,
where k,l>0.
```

Keeping one constraint fixed the function g(x)/g(y) is a concave function. It is also checked by Matlab simulations by various k and l. The simulation result of g(x,y) also gives concave function. What is the maximum value of g(x,y) when two constraints are present?

Comment: This sounds like a request for homework help. Per the guidelines at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, please include a "description of the difficulty you are having solving it" for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try `fmincon` like below

```
fn = @(v) -(v(1)*k+(1-v(1))*log(1+((v(1)*v(2))*l)/(1-v(1))));
Xopt = fmincon(fn,[0.5,0.5],[],[],[],[],[0;0]+eps,[1;1]-eps);
```

**Example**

```
k = 5;
l = 2;
fn = @(v) -(v(1)*k+(1-v(1))*log(1+((v(1)*v(2))*l)/(1-v(1))));
Xopt = fmincon(fn,[0.5,0.5],[],[],[],[],[0;0]+eps,[1;1]-eps);
```

such that

```
>> Xopt
Xopt =

   0.99800
   0.54714
```

Comment: How to prove mathematically?

Comment: Is there any way to generalize the solution w.r.t. k and l ?

Comment: @new if you want math proof, maybe you should migrate your post to stackexchange or cross validated. Stackoverflow mainly has coding issues for discussions.

Comment: @new do you have any constraint on `k` and `l`? if there is, then you can take them into account when using `fmincon`

Comment: The only constraint is k,l>0. I want a solution with any value of k and l. Is that possible?

Comment: @new if there are no upper bounds on `k` or `l`, you may have `inf` if you take `k = inf` for example

Comment: while running the above-mentioned code I am getting always the value of v(2)=1. Can you please check that? and regarding the generalizing (not fixing them) the k and l value can you please share the code? I am getting one error.

Comment: @new If you like you can try the code below, but I don't think it gives the right answer since the max value for all possible `k` and `l` should be infinite: `fn = @(v) -(v(1)*v(3)+(1-v(1))*log(1+((v(1)*v(2))*v(4))/(1-v(1))));
[Xopt, fval] = fmincon(fn,[0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5],[],[],[],[],[0;0;0;0]+eps,[1;1;Inf;Inf]-eps);`

Comment: thanks a lot. I am also stuck in another one simulation .. can you please check - ```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61226954/what-is-the-solution-of-the-following-optimization-problem-with-linear-and-non-l```

Comment: @new I will take a look at your another post. By the way, if you think my answer address your problem or do help, please feel free to upvote/accept it, thanks!

Comment: @ThomasisIsCoding Can you please tell me why you have considered +eps and -eps?

Comment: @new the boundaries `0` and `1` are not  feasible for your objective function, mathematically

Comment: Can u please help in a Matlab question? ```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61397205/how-to-solve-the-error-of-my-following-problem?noredirect=1#comment108620518_61397205```

Comment: @new if you think my answer address your problem or do help, please consider to accept it, thanks! I will take a look at your new question

Comment: Sure. Thanks for reminding me. It would be better if you can provide a solution for my new problem.  Again I am stuck in ```fmincon```.

Comment: @new From your code I don't know what do you want to minimize, you need to design it according to your context. If you just want to get a scalar return value, you have a lot of options, e.g., `norm(x)`, `min(x)` and so on

Comment: No, I need a vector.

Comment: @New I know you need a vector output from `fmincom`, but your `objective` must give a scalar as return value, otherwise `fmincon` has no clue how to minmize

Comment: For each and every variable I have given the ranges. For a particular input, there is some optimum value ```x(11)```. For a optimum```x(11)```  there will be some optimum values of other variables. I need those all. If we can save that or take out by some function . Then it is also fine. Can we make any code like the following:```fn = @(v) -(v(1)*v(3)+(1-v(1))*log(1+((v(1)*v(2))*v(4))/(1-v(1)))); [Xopt, fval] = fmincon(fn,[0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5],[],[],[],[],[0;0;0;0]+eps,[1;1;Inf;Inf]-eps);```

Comment: @new As you see, `fn` takes vector `v` as the input, but returns a scalar. I don't know what kind of `fn` fits your `X` vector, since each elements in `X` should have its own weights (different contribution to the final scalar output). You need to define it by yourself, since I have no contexts to do that